# Rextester Language Compilation C++ Issue

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, clang++

I have been using [rextester](https://rextester.com) for various languages and it has been working really efficiently. It is just causing problem for 1 language which is the C++ (clang)

**Params are as follow:-**

```
LanguageChoice: C++ (clang) = 27
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}

Input: Is empty

CompilerArgs: -Wall -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -o a.out source_file.cpp
```

This is the URL I've been hitting:

https://rextester.com/rundotnet/api?LanguageChoice=27&Program=#includeint main(){std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";}&Input=&CompilerArgs=-Wall -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -o a.out source_file.cpp

> Response: {
>       "Warnings": null,
>       "Errors": "Compiler args must contain '-o a.out'",
>       "Result": null,
>       "Stats": "Compilation time: 0 sec, absolute service time: 0 sec",
>       "Files": null }

[Url in the chorme](https://rextester.com/rundotnet/api?LanguageChoice=27&Program=#include%20%3Ciostream%3E%20int%20main()%20%7B%20std::cout%20%3C%3C%20%22Hello,%20world!%5Cn%22;%20%7D&Input=&CompilerArgs=-Wall%20-std=c%20%2014%20-stdlib=libc%20%20%20-O2%20-o%20a.out%20source_file.cpp)

Kindly help!

Comment: Can't reproduce, perhaps a temporary rextester glitch.

Comment: Can you share the link? @n.m.

Comment: It looks like you are mis-coding the + character. Look at your URL carefully. In POST requests + means space. You need to percent-encode it.

Comment: you should use http POST, not GET

Answer (score 2):

I took CompilerArgs right from the rextexter site and added newline after include  and the link worked properly:
it looked like this: https://rextester.com/rundotnet/api?LanguageChoice=27&Program=%23include%3Ciostream%3E%0Aint%20main()%20%7B%20std::cout%20%3C%3C%20%22Hello,%20world!%5Cn%22;%20%7D&Input=&CompilerArgs=-Wall%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%20-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B%20-O2%20-o%20a.out%20source_file.cpp